# Is there a function in MySQL to return the VERY beginning of a week for a given date?

Tags: mysql

So, let's say the current date is `2022-03-04 10:45:26`, I want to have a query retuning every entry after `2022-02-27 00:00:00`.

I have found `SUBDATE(eventDate, WEEKDAY(eventDate))` but this is not precise enough.

In other words, this is the query I am looking for

```
SELECT * 
FROM ts_punch_events
WHERE eventDate > "2022-02-27 00:00:00";
```

But using a parameter, like `NOW()` or a user-defined one, to filter the results.

In other words, I'm looking for a way to have a "function" returning this

```
fn("2022-03-04 10:45:26");   ->   "2022-02-26 00:00:00"
fn("2022-01-07 09:38:43");   ->   "2022-01-02 00:00:00"
fn(NOW())                    ->   ... first day of the week at 00:00:00
```

The equivalent in JavaScript would be [startOfWeek](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/startOfWeek).

```
// The start of a week for 2 September 2014 11:55:00:
const result = startOfWeek(new Date(2014, 8, 2, 11, 55, 0))
//=> Sun Aug 31 2014 00:00:00
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DATE(eventDate - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(eventDate) + 1) MOD 7 DAY) AS week_start
FROM datatable
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f3ede945ed02693b47d5f9fb2018ea6e

Comment: Thank you! This is a simple solution!

Comment: this does return a date, not a datetime.  if you want a datetime, wrap it like: `select timestamp(date( ... ))`

Comment: @ysth MySQL have soft datatype system. DATE is treated as DATETIME with zero timepart when the context needs in DATETIME/TIMESTAMP value. So there is no any problem. The only situation when this may produce incorrect result is the query CREATE TABLE .. SELECT with this expression as silently defined column.